# Fulfilling missing .so file in libftdi

Tags: linux, ftdi

I am using ft232r library provided by ftdi for programming an LPC11C14 micro-controller through Linux Mint. To initialize the software, I need to run the following command:

```
./ft232r_prog --manufacturer Sunswift --product $(PROJECT_NAME) --invert_rts --invert_dtr
```

When I run the code, I get the following issue:

```
Error while loading shared libraries: libftdi.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

on running ldd ft232r_prog, I get:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77b8000)
libusb-0.1.so.4 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4 (0xf7790000)
libftdi.so.1 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf75e5000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77b9000)
```

The file `libftdi.so.1` is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Since the executable ft232r_prog is unable to find the .so file, I have tried the following:

1. Updated the path environment variable to contain /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -- Failed
2. Updated the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to contain `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` -- Failed
3. Ran `ldconfig` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` -- Failed

This appears to be a common issue with including shared libraries. Any ideas on how I can resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your system is 64-bit and the program is 32-bit. In this case, you need to install the 32-bit version of the library.

Comment: Thanks, H2CO3. ft232r_prog was an executable created for a 32-bit system. My friend recompiled the source library for a 64-bit system and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

To install 32-bit version of libftdi on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 try following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libftdi1:i386
```